# ReportViewer asp.net webform, sales report. Click to expand row detail. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, webforms

I'm trying to do a sales report that lists each order with a little plus icon beside it, once clicked the order row should expand to show the order details. I'm using the reportviewer for the first time and having it working to show the basic order info.

What I'd like to have now is each row expand when clicked to show the order details. So row 1 might list the buyers name, address etc and when clicked you see what they bought.

Given that I'm totally new at this kind of reporting (never heard of Tablix before using this reportviewer) is there a relatively easy way of displaying this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check http://www.gotreportviewer.com/?

Comment: Here is how you toggle visibility: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251711%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Had seen that site before alright but back when I was trying to get the initial report to display. Am I right in thinking that what I'm looking for is called a drillthrough report, or is that something else?

Comment: Just had a quick look and the drillthrough seems to accommodate the display of data after clicking through from the inital report. Whiel not ideal that will do. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.